# Image gallery display like zoom in using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

Please look below the URL,

http://www.wix.com/sujatatibre/wwwwixcomsujatatibre

- In that site they displaying the slideshow using flash. Can we display the images using jquery like that?. I surf the web but i can't find jquery like that.

Comment: just right click on the animation if it is flash it will show up saying flash . that way you can see if the animation is being played using flash plugin. And ofcourse this type of animation effect is possible using javascript. just need to make it your self if it is already not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do something with [ContentFlow](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/) and [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/).